# Strange distinct working with JSON, for various version of PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

For SQL-code like this

```sql
WITH irregularGridPointJSON (bufferRow) AS (
    VALUES
    ('[
        {
          "id": 8054,
          "y": 35.62450698,
          "x": 59.17406342,
          "area": 1024000000
        },
        {
          "id": 8055,
          "y": 35.60011194,
          "x": 59.52363861,
          "area": 1024000000
        }
      ]'::json)
)
SELECT power(CAST(json_array_elements(bufferRow)->>'x' AS real), 
           CAST(json_array_elements(bufferRow)->>'y' AS real)) 
       AS sample
FROM 
irregularGridPointJSON;
```

I see that for PostgreSQL 9.6 [this code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tPa9MPJyqPxdwvxppT7uf9/0) cause error.

**Query Error: error:** functions and operators can take at most one set argument

But for PostgreSQL 10.0 [same sql-code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kwamQnvYuSTG65nRXw1B6Q/0) do not cause error. I do not find anything about this in PostgreSQL documentation :(.

**Edited 20.12.2019.** I use for PostgreSQL 9.6 something like this,

```sql
WITH irregularGridPointJSON (bufferRow) AS (
    VALUES
    ('[
        {
          "id": 8054,
          "y": 35.62450698,
          "x": 59.17406342,
          "area": 1024000000
        },
        {
          "id": 8055,
          "y": 35.60011194,
          "x": 59.52363861,
          "area": 1024000000
        }
      ]'::json)
),
bufferSourceData AS (
  SELECT buffer.id, buffer.y, buffer.x, buffer.area 
  FROM 
      irregularGridPointJSON,
      json_to_recordset(irregularGridPointJSON.bufferRow) AS buffer(id integer, y real, x real, area real)
)
SELECT power(x, y) AS sample
FROM bufferSourceData;
```

but **CROSS JOIN** with **LATERAL** maybe useful.

Comment: Can you include the error output of the error from postgresql?

Comment: I did this. And in question`s text contains two links on samples on fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an explicit lateral cross join. That should work for both versions.

```
SELECT power((jae.e->>'x')::real, 
             (jae.e->>'y')::real) sample
       FROM irregulargridpointjson igpj
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(igpj.bufferrow) jae
                                                                   (e);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a section that alludes to this in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET):

> Before PostgreSQL 10, putting more than one set-returning function in the same select list did not behave very sensibly unless they always produced equal numbers of rows. Otherwise, what you got was a number of output rows equal to the least common multiple of the numbers of rows produced by the set-returning functions. Also, nested set-returning functions did not work as described above; instead, **a set-returning function could have at most one set-returning argument**, and each nest of set-returning functions was run independently.

(emphasis mine)

In any case, I think it's much clearer to use a lateral join as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: I did not see this. That is very helpful.